# Ternary if statement without else not working with &&

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I'm trying to convert my code that works into an arrow function (I'm relatively new to arrow functions) but don't know why it doesn't work with &&. I thought that ternary if statements with else uses ? and : whereas it uses && without the else statement.

Why does the following not work:

```
courses.forEach((course) =>
      tutors.forEach((tutor) =>
        tutor.id == course.id &&
        course["name"] = tutor.name
        //console.log(1) has no errors
      )
    );
```

This works, where I had to use an else statement, aka `: 1`

```
courses.forEach((course) =>
      tutors.forEach((tutor) =>
        tutor.id == course.id ?
        course["name"] = tutor.name : 1
      )
    );
```

Here's the solution without arrow functions, so basically the solution is just converting the below into a arrow functions:

```
courses.forEach(function(course) {
  tutors.forEach(function(tutor) {
    if (tutor.id == course.id) {
      course["name"] = tutor.name;
    }
  });
});
```

Any explanation on what I'm doing wrong, or any tips about how to best convert into arrow functions would be great. Thanks for any help here.

```js
let tutors = [
   {
     name: "Beth",
     age: 37,
      id: 1
   },
   {
     name: "Bob",
     age: 32,
      id: 2
   },
   {
     name: "Jack",
     age: 63,
      id: 3
   },
   {
     name: "Jess",
     age: 17,
      id: 4
   }
 ],
  courses = [
    {
      code: "AA01",
      description: "Javascript IIFEs, maps, filters, reduces, etc",
      id: 3
    },
    {
      code: "AO83",
      description: "Arrays, for of loops, etc",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      code: "AX40",
      description: "CSS, HTML",
      id: 3
    },
    {
      code: "BX92",
      description: "SQL, Node",
      id: 2
    },
    {
      code: "CC24",
      description: "PHP, Java",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      code: "DI30",
      description: "MongoDB",
      id: 4
    }
  ];

/*
courses.forEach(function(course) {
  tutors.forEach(function(tutor) {
    if (tutor.id == course.id) {
      course["name"] = tutor.name;
    }
  });
});
*/


courses.forEach((course) =>
  tutors.forEach(function(tutor) {
    if (tutor.id == course.id) {
      course["name"] = tutor.name;
    }
  })
);

/*
courses.forEach((course) =>
  tutors.forEach(function(tutor) {
    if (tutor.id == course.id) {
      course["name"] = tutor.name;
    }
  })
);
*/

/*
courses.forEach((course) =>
  tutors.forEach((tutor) =>
    tutor.id == course.id ?
    course["name"] = tutor.name : 1
  )
);
*/

courses.forEach((course) =>
  tutors.forEach((tutor) =>
    tutor.id == course.id &&
    course["name"] = tutor.name
    //console.log(1) has no errors
  )
);
```

Comment: Don't forget you can write arrow functions on multiple lines if you use curly brackets with a manual "return" statement if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
courses.map((cours) => cours["name"] = tutors.find(tutor => tutor.id === cours.id).name)
```

assuming that every course have tutors that share the same id

### using `forEach`

```
courses.forEach((cours) => cours["name"] = tutors.find(tutor => tutor.id === cours.id).name)
```

and `&&` didn't work in some cases because the runtime think that you are replacing the value with left-side

#### Work

```
courses.forEach((course) =>
  tutors.forEach((tutor) =>
    tutor.id === course.id &&
    (course["name"] = tutor.name)
  )
);
```

#### Does Not

```
courses.forEach((course) =>
  tutors.forEach((tutor) =>
    tutor.id == course.id &&
    course["name"] = tutor.name
  )
)
```

Comment: Does it work if you wrap the "Does Not" inner function in curly brackets?

Comment: No, the problem is with the line `tutor.id == course.id && course["name"] = tutor.name` no matter what you do to the function, if this line does not change it will not work because of the `left-hand side in assignment` Error, which you can solve by wrapping (`course["name"] = tutor.name`) because it will replace the value and return the value.